# How can I make a SliverAppBar that is similar to Google News?

Tags: flutter, dart, sliverappbar

I want a standard AppBar when the app starts, however, once the user begins scrolling I want the app bar to slide up and off the screen. However, when that happens, the status bar (on iOS) doesn't have a background. I don't want to set a constant background directly to the status bar using something like [flutter_statusbarcolor](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_statusbarcolor) because that leaves a solid color, which isn't a widget.

[image: Before scroll] [image: After Scroll]

The only solution I have right now is to just keep the AppBar pined.

However, what I really want to do is what Google News does. The AppBar slides up almost all the way, however, it stays under the app bar with some opacity.

How Google News does it:

[image]

Is there any way to do this with Flutter and SliverAppBar without doing it a hacky way? The only thing I'm thinking is doing it with a stack, however, how would I know how to keep it under the status bar, as Android already has some opacity under the status bar.

Answer (score 1):

I used `OrientationBuilder` widget to listen to changes in orientation, as when there are changes to the orientation the status bar hight can change.

Then I used [`FlutterStatusbarManager`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_statusbar_manager) package to get the height of the status bar. `FlutterStatusbarManager.getHeight` is a `future` so it needed to be wrapped with a `FutureBuilder`

Here is the full example code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_statusbar_manager/flutter_statusbar_manager.dart';

class FixedStatusbarBackground extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const FixedStatusbarBackground({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        child,
        OrientationBuilder(
          builder: (context, Orientation orientation) => FutureBuilder<double>(
              future: FlutterStatusbarManager.getHeight,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Container(
                      height: snapshot.data,
                      color: Theme.of(context)
                          .appBarTheme
                          .color
                          .withOpacity(.7) //Colors.white.withOpacity(.7),
                      );
                } else {
                  return Container();
                }
              }),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The `child` widget that is passed in is the entire `CustomScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll widgets in flutter have controllers that inform what's going on with the scroll. You can get how much the sliver has been scrolled and change it's opacity, content and size accordingly. It's not going to be simple though, but take a look at [ScrollController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html), used by the [CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html).